# Initalising hidden elements with ShinyJS

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, leaflet, shinyjs

I'd like to hide an element when a shiny app starts, but unlike [this example](https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyjs/man/hidden.html), the element to be hidden is part of a larger element which is visible.

In this example, the element to be hidden at the start is the drawing control which is part of a leaflet map.  There is a button which toggles the visibility of the drawing control - how can I have it start with the drawing control hidden?  The full code for the app follows below.

[image]

```
library(rbgm)
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  actionBttn("toggle_button", "Toggle drawing")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    set.seed(2)
    fs <- sample(bgmfiles::bgmfiles(), 1)

    model <- boxSpatial(bgmfile(fs))
    model <- spTransform(model, "+init=epsg:4326")

    m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles() 

    m <- m %>% addPolygons(data = model, group = 'model') %>%     
      addDrawToolbar(targetGroup = 'model',
                     editOptions = editToolbarOptions(
                       selectedPathOptions = selectedPathOptions()))
    m
  })

  observe({
    shinyjs::hide(selector = "div.leaflet-draw") # <---- this doesn't hide the draw controls at the start!!
  })

  observeEvent(input$toggle_button, {
    shinyjs::toggle(selector = "div.leaflet-draw")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've tried using `observe` to hide the element at the start however it doesn't do anything, presumably because the drawing control element loads after the observe event fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
shinyjs::delay(0, shinyjs::hide(selector = "div.leaflet-draw"))
```

(without observer).

---

## EDIT

Another solution:

```
js <- "
$(document).on('shiny:value', function(e){
  if(e.name === 'mymap'){
    setTimeout(function(){$('div.leaflet-draw').hide();}, 0);
  }
});
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(tags$script(js)),
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  ...
```

Comment: This worked - until I applied it to my app which sources data online - increasing the delay time is hit and miss.  Is there a way to make sure it triggers after the map or page has been loaded regardless of load time?

Comment: @Vlad Hmmm... I can't say like that. Could you share an example which sources data online ?

Comment: @Vlad I've just edited my answer to add another solution. Could you try this one?

Comment: Your edited solution worked even with a long delay.